# How many Semaphores can a system store?

Tags: c, linux, ipc, semaphore

Every system has a maximum number of IPC objects that can be "stored". I have to create a set of semaphores that contains hundreds of semaphores. Now I have 2 questions:
1) are those semaphores counted as distinct IPC objects or a set of semaphores is counted by the system as a unique IPC object? 
2) how many semaphores can a set of semaphores contain?

Comment: maybe `man lsipc` is good starting point.

Comment: There are *several* kinds of semaphores - you should find out *what kind of* semaphores you actually need to use...

Comment: General rule: Unless it's a resource constrained by `ulimit` or `sysctl` it's usually only constrained by available memory or disk space. Some "IPC objects" are just locations in memory, so they're unconstrained. Others, like shared memory, are tightly constrained.

Comment: thanks to all the people that answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Every system has obliviously a different maximum number of semaphore sets that can be stored. 
Using those command:

```
              ipcs -ls

                 OR

       cat /proc/sys/kernel/sem
```

you can see your system limits.

I find the answer in this page (Chapter 8 talks about my problem)
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html-single/tuning_and_optimizing_red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_oracle_9i_and_10g_databases/index#chap-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Setting_Shared_Memory